# E-Book-Reader Style Desktop Environment for 11.10?

Tags: desktop-environments, ebooks

Out of many desktop environments available around i wanted to know which satisfy my needs. 
I want
1) Quick Minimal Desktop.
2)Support for pdf and doc,  No need of video.
3)Need wifi, no need of BT and Ether.
4)Super Long Battery life.
5) Minimal Browser

Comment: Any Browser in Maximized mode does that exactly...You'll need to make a Kiosk type session for that.

Comment: pls tell what does it mean by kiosk type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet here is to use Openbox, avalible through `sudo apt-get install openbox`. It's a very minimalistic desktop enviroment thet uses barely any RAM. When you first login, all you get is a blank blue screen. Ri-ght-click the desktop and select "Open Terminal". From there you can type commands to acess the web browser for acessing the internet, calibre for reading ebooks, etc. This type will give you a very long battery life because of the minimal resources used. You can also tell the CPU speed to run at a lower spees, the computer will run more slowly but it will lengthen battery life. To do this, see the program cpudynd at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/cpudynd.8.html.